# Web API 2 controller does not accept QueryString parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a GET() controller to retrieve a list of entities. I want to pass a parameter to the action to filter the list of objects returned as follows:

```
Mysite.com/Users?nameContains=john
```

This is my action definition:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(string nameContains)
{
    // I want to use nameContains here
}
```

I get an error:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

If I revert the method to not get that parameter, it works.

Comment: Try to send as body object. You can get then

Comment: How you define your route?

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I'd rather not to because it wouldn't be compliant to the RESTful API best practices.

@ssilas777
`config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: @NadavMiller Best practise in Web Api send parameter as body or define in URL and map that in registerRoute

Comment: @AmitAgrawal Where did you get that "best practice" advice because I've never heard of it before?

Comment: This should work, there must be something else going on that you are not showing.

Comment: Your URI should be `mysite.Com/api/users?namecontains=foo`. You are missing the `api` path segment

Comment: @DarrelMiller my mistake, i do include the api part, i just didn't mention it in the question.

Comment: There is something you are not showing us.  I just tested almost exactly the same scenario and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get([FromUri] string nameContains)
{
    // I want to use nameContains here
}
```

Also since you are working in Web Api 2, you can make use of [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

```
[Route("users")]
public IEnumerable<object> Get([FromUri] string nameContains)
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was my mistake, I used 2 parameters and I didn't pass one of them (nor assigned it a default value) so it returned an error. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new route to the `WebApiConfig` entries.

For instance, your method definition:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Get(string nameContains)
{
    // I want to use nameContains here
}
```

add:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetSampleObject",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{nameContains}"
);
```

Then add the parameters to the HTTP call:

```
GET //<service address>/Api/Data/test
```

or use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your method

```
// uri: /Api/Data/test 
public IEnumerable<object> Get()
{
    NameValueCollection nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
    var contains = nvc["nameContains"];
    // BL with nameContains here
}
```

Comment: There should be no need to do this.  Query parameter mapping does work.